# How does the proof of the Second Isomorphism theorem of rings prove this theorem?

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic, ring-theory, proof-explanation, ring-isomorphism

The theorem is :

> Let $I$ be an ideal of the ring $R$.
> Then there is a one-to-one correspondence between the subrings of $R/I$ and the subrings of $R$ containing $I$, given as follows: to a subring $S$ of $R$ containing $I$ corresponds the subring $ S/I $ of $R/I$. Under this correspondence, ideals of $R/I$ correspond to ideals of $R$ containing $I$; and, if $J$ is an ideal of $R$ containing $I$, then
> $(R/I)/(J/I) \cong R/J$

I understood everything in the proof, however they prove it as if it were an equivalence, and not a bijection, what am I missing?
The equivalence would be
$$ (\exists S)(S\leq R\ \land\ I\subset S\ \land\ A=S/I)\quad \iff\quad A\leq R/I.$$
But in the theorem they stated a function like this:
$$ \Phi : \{S:S \leq R \land I \subset S \} \mapsto \{A: A\leq R/I \} $$

Would be a bijection. I've seen this in many points of view, asked my colleagues, teacher, older colleagues and didn't get satisfied with any answer.

I tried to see it, the implication in this direction $\rightarrow$ prove that it's well defined and $\leftarrow$ proves that it's surjective, but where is injectivity?
Another way is, $\rightarrow $ proves that it's a function and $\leftarrow$ proves that it's inverse is also a function, so it's a bijection, but I'm not so conviced with this argument, could someone help me?
Can I prove bijections with equivalences?

Comment: You state you're having trouble understanding a proof. It would help if you could include the relevant parts of the proof; as it stands it's rather unclear what the proof looks like, and what part of it you don't understand.

Comment: Also, the equivalence doesn't quite make sense; if the left hand side is not satisfied, then the right hand side may be undefined. What is $S/I$ supposed to mean if $S$ does not contain $I$? Or if $S$ is not a subring of $R$?

Comment: I understand the whole proof, I can post it here. What I don't understand is, the proof is based on the equivalence, and I don't see how the equivalence proves the bijection.

You'e right, it doesn't make sense, but the left side would mean, it A is a subring of R/I, then there is a subring S of R such that A=S/I

Comment: You're right, that is a correct formulation of the other implication, and this implication is equivalent to $\Phi$ being surjective. And indeed the implication
$$S\leq R\ \wedge\ I\leq S\quad\implies\quad S/I\leq R/I,$$
is equivalent to $\Phi$ being well-defined. But the fact that $\Phi$ is injective is *not* captured by these two implications together.

Comment: Also note that because the original equivalence is not true (it isn't even well-defined as it stands), so proving it should be impossible, and so any proof via this equivalence is wrong.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused about the situation; you state that
$$\text{"I understood everything in the proof, however they prove it as if it were an equivalence..."}.$$
Who are *"they"*? Is this equivalence stated in the proof? If so, then apparently you haven't understood everything in the proof. If it is not stated in the proof, then who states this where, and why is it relevant?

Comment: You're right, I made that equivalence and it's wrong. however I saw the proof on the "book" Notes on Algebraic Structures by Peter J. Cameron (can I post the link here?) It's on page 35 in the book.
But I understood every step in the proof

Comment: For future reference, you can post a link in a comment by using the format `[link text](link url)`. Square brackets for the text, followed by round brackets for the url.

Comment: And indeed the text you cite does not prove uniqueness/injectivity, what a shame!

Comment: Exactly, this makes me wonder, are we missing any other way of viewing this proof?

Comment: The proof is really just a routine verification, as my answer shows.

Answer (score 1):

On its own, given a ring $R$ and an ideal $I\subset R$, the logical statement
$$S \leq R\quad \land\quad I \subset S\qquad \iff\qquad S/I \leq R/I,$$
doesn't quite make sense; if the left hand side is not satisfied, then the right hand side may be *undefined*. What is $S/I$ supposed to mean if $I\not\subset S$? Or worse, if $S\not\leq R$? (I take it that $S\leq R$ means that $S$ is a subring of $R$.)

As you suggest in the comments, you might instead prove the two equivalences
\begin{eqnarray*}
&&S \leq R\ \land\ I \subset S\ &\Longrightarrow&\qquad S/I \leq R/I,\\
(\exists S)(&&S\leq R\ \land\ I\subset S\ \land\ A=S/I)\qquad &\Longleftarrow&\qquad \hspace{9pt}A\leq R/I.
\end{eqnarray*}
The first is equivalent to $\Phi$ being well-defined, the second is equivalent to $\Phi$ being surjective. Neither shows that $\Phi$ is injective; this is equivalent to the $S$ in the second implication being *unique*. So the claim that $\Phi$ is a bijection is equivalent to the implication
$$(\exists!S)(S\leq R\ \land\ I\subset S\ \land\ A=S/I)\qquad \Longleftarrow\qquad A\leq R/I.$$

Comment: Right, it serves, but in the many proofs I saw, they don't prove the unicity of S.

Comment: @NunoMateus I'm sorry to hear that, because the uniqueness is the only (slightly) nontrivial point to prove. I'm glad I could provide you with the first complete proof then.

Comment: Thanks  for the proof ^^